# How can I strip all non digits in a string except the first character?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string that I want to make sure that the format is always a `+` followed by digits.
The following would work:

```
String parsed = inputString.replaceAll("[^0-9]+", "");  
if(inputString.charAt(0) == '+') {  
   result = "+" + parsed;  
}  
else {
  result = parsed;  
}
```

But is there a way to have a regex in the `replaceAll` that would keep the `+` (if exists) in the beginning of the string and replace all non digits in the first line?

Comment: NB: `replaceAll` will not add the `+` in case there's none, so I don't see what you are looking for

Comment: [This regex](https://regex101.com/r/pI6qH3/2) should work, I believe: search for `(^[+])|[^0-9]+` and replace with `$1`.

Comment: From your code, you seem to allow inputs such as `abd+3G45;{`, which doesn't quite make sense to me. You might want to asserts that the input matches some sort of pattern `[+]?\s*\d+\s*` instead (whitelisting).

Answer (score 3):

The following statement with the given regex would do the job:

```
String result = inputString.replaceAll("(^\\+)|[^0-9]", "$1");
```

---

```
(^\\+)    find either a plus sign at the beginning of string and put it to a group ($1),
|         or
[^0-9]    find a character which is not a number
$1        and replace it with nothing or the plus sign at the start of group ($1)
```

Comment: The `+` is lost in input such as `+345HHHH`

Comment: @nhahtdh Thanks for figuring it out. I changed the regex by replacing the `?` (zero or one) with a `|` (or). Now it correctly outputs `+345`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this expression:

```
String r = s.replaceAll("((?<!^)[^0-9]|^[^0-9+])", "");
```

The idea is to replace any non-digit when it is not the initial character of the string (that's the `(?<!^)[^0-9]` part with a lookbehind) or any character that is not a digit or plus that is the initial character of the string (the `^[^0-9+]` part).

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/3QXMoP)

Comment: But the only acceptable non-digit as initial character of the string is `+`. This regex allows any non character, right?

Comment: Equivalent to `.replaceAll("(^\\+)?[^0-9]+", "$1")`, no?

Comment: @Jim No, only plus `+` is allowed. Please see the demo. One of the input strings is `"a56b78"`, it becomes `5678`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight:How is the `+` reinforced? I am not sure which part of the expression keeps the `+`

Comment: @Jim `[^0-9+]` allows plus (note how it is on the other side of the bracket). Did you try it out? Let me know if you find a counterexample.

Answer (score 2):

What about just

```
(?!^)\D+
```

Java string:

```
"(?!^)\\D+"
```

[Demo at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/yK4oQ1/1)

- `\D` matches a character that is not a digit `[^0-9]`
- `(?!^)` using a negative [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to check, if it is not the initial character

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use this kind of replacement:

```
String parsed = inputString.replaceAll("^[^0-9+]*(\\+)|[^0-9]+", "$1");
```

if present and before the first digit in the string, the `+` character is captured in group 1. For example: `dfd+sdfd12+sdf12` returns `+1212` (the second `+` is removed since its position is after the first digit).

Answer (score 0):

try this

1- This will allow  negative and positive number and will match app special  char except   - and +  at  first position.

```
(?!^[-+])[^0-9.]
```

2- If you only want to allow  + at  first position

```
(?!^[+])[^0-9.]
```